# Inconsistent Results with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I'm having some trouble with a SQL Server 2008 R2 (Express) installation. It seems like there are two tables operating in "parallel".

If I run the following query:

```
USE [database];
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[events] WHERE 1=1;
```

I get the results I expect. However, if I run this query, I get a dataset that is completely wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[events] WHERE 1=1;
```

Data is being sent into the database by a variety of programs -- so obviously one (or more) of these apps is doing something wrong. The apps connect to database via a C# LINQ --> SQL DBML, the DBML (which I cannot modify) uses `events` as the table name (ideally it would use `dbo.events`, but I can't modify/recreate it.)

Has anyone seen this before? Is there some way to make the two queries equivalent? I can recreate the database if necessary - the data in there is not critical.

If I load up the database in SQL Management Studio and right click to select "Select top [1000] rows" -- it executes the second query (the one that gives me the wrong results...).

Edit:

- There is only 1 instance in play (as far as I know anyway -- don't have access to the server right now, will check tomorrow)
- The two tables are totally different. Query 1 results in 2,000 or so items. Query 2 results in 20,000 or so items. All items are unique.

Comment: Sure there aren't two different instances in play?

Comment: In what sense "completely wrong"? I'd start off by checking the rowcounts as they should be identical. If they *are* identical yhen I'd stick and `ORDER BY` on the selects. Although the probability is that SQL Server is querying the data in exactly the same way, it's a horrendously quick sanity check. Once that's checked out then it's worth looking at other possibilities (e.g., you aren't running multiple instances of SQL on one server and connecting to different ones). Basically what you're seeing just sounds wrong from a fairly fundamental level, so it's worth checking all the basics first.

Comment: Well, your select top1000 in sql studio cannot return 2000 results... Do you not limit your result set somewhere else also? What hapens if you execute select count(*) both ways?

Comment: The numbers I provided are from a count(*) query. There's nothing else limiting the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Martin is correct. Someone messed up this particular server and created tables with the exact same names in a different database, then set some incorrect settings to make the bad database the default.

Deleting the bogus database fixed the problem.